# Is using a swing an example of normal or of parametric resonance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, resonance

Parametric resonance is a situation where the driving frequency is a multiple of the eigenfrequency. Various people say that using a swing and propelling it oneself is such a case, with the driving frequency being the double of the eigenfrequency. But when I use a swing, as I did today, my own motion has the same frequency as that of the swing, not twice the frequency.

An example description is http://www.hk-phy.org/articles/swing/swing_e.html which claims that self-propelled swinging is normal resonance.

The opposite is said here: [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_oscillator)

What is the correct view: is self-propelled swinging normal resonance or is it parametric resonance?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245632/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/749947/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159741/226902

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a father pushing a child, it's normal resonance.

In the case of a child driving the motion itself it's parametric resonance. The Wikipedia article you mentioned states: *For example, a well known parametric oscillator is a child pumping a swing by periodically standing and squatting to increase the size of the swing's oscillations.*

Comment: Kvothe, I read that as well; but a child usually pushes with the same frequency as the swing; that is NOT parametric resonance. It is only parametric if it happens with double or threefold or fourfold etc frequency, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because of pages like http://www.elmer.unibas.ch/pendulum/parres.htm or also http://faculty.ifmo.ru/butikov/Applets/Par_resonance.pdf - am I misunderstanding them?

Comment: Also the Wikipedia pages says: "Parametric resonance occurs in a mechanical system when a system is parametrically excited and oscillates at one of its resonant frequencies. Parametric resonance takes place when the external excitation frequency equals TWICE the natural frequency of the system. Parametric excitation differs from forcing since the action appears as a time varying modification on a system parameter. The classical example of parametric resonance is that of the vertically forced pendulum."

Comment: @Gianna As far as I can see the big difference is the driving mechanism. If you forget about resonance for a moment, do you understand the fundamental difference between the two examples I listed in my answer?

Comment: My question is *not* about a child standing up and down on a swing. The question is about a child that moves its head back and forward on a swing (and its legs the other way), like everybody usually does: is that normal resonance or parametric resonance? It seems to me that this is normal resonance, not parametric resonance.

Comment: Those two methods are effectively the same.