# Forced Oscillations & Resonance

Tags: oscillators, resonance

I need a very much **physical** explanation for the phenomenon of Resonance associated with forced oscillations (damped). I have gone through *HRW* and *Concepts of Physics* by H C Verma, but that wasn't of much use for me.

I got some mathematical idea of the thing, but still I'm not confident.

Comment: Have a look at this http://web.pdx.edu/~larosaa/Ph-223/Lecture-Notes-Ph-213/PH-213_Chapter-15_FORCED_OSCILLATIONS_and-RESONANCE_(complete-version).pdf

Comment: Why not do a google search ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resonance** is when you push a kid on a swing.

If you do it right, you make him swing higher (You push him in the same direction as he is moving). If you do it wrong, you stop his swinging (e.g. pushing, when he is on the way backwards).

---

When you "add to" or "build up" the amplitude of the oscillations, **this is resonance**.

You need to push with the same frequency as he is swinging. (If he is swinging back-and-forth in 3 seconds, then you must push forward exactly once every 3 seconds). Also you must be in phase. (Even when your push-frequency is equal to his swing-frequency, you should not push when he is moving backwards.)

[image]

> I need a very much physical explanation for the phenomenon of Resonance associated with forced oscillations (damped)

A damped oscillation only changes amplitude with time. Not frequency. Resonance is not different in this case.

If you want a steady oscillation with constant amplitude, then of course you need to force an oscillation on the system and reach resonance to cancel out the damping.

Comment: Note in the swing example if the parent pushes and imparts the same amount of energy that is lost by wind friction and frictional losses in the pendulum pivot joints for one cycle, then the oscillation reaches a stable limit cycle of constant amplitude. If less energy the amplitude decreases. If more energy the amplitude increases. If the parent stops pushing, all the energy eventually drains out and the child eventually comes to rest. Damping is just synonymous with energy losses.

Comment: In practical systems there is always energy losses so to perpetually maintain a resonance you need to provide an energy source to make up for the loss.

Comment: @docscience: nice interpretation

Comment: @Steeven Awesome! Cleared up some confusion for me too!