# Swing: why does the body position modify the amplitude?

Tags: energy-conservation, oscillators, resonance

When a person swings, why does the amplitude of oscillations increase if the person changes the body position ?
That is, when descending and approaching the vertical position, if the person extend his legs and changes the body position almost horizontally, the amplitude increases.
I can sense that it has to do with the center of gravity, but i don't understand where the added energy comes from ?

Comment: You're feeding energy into the system by changing the effective length of the pendulum (distance from pivot point to your center of mass), thus performing work against the centrifugal force. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXo6WvHRs_I) explains it quite well.

Answer (score -1):

You are not adding energy, but changing the rotational inertia (of the person relativ to the center point of the rotation/swinging).

In the bottom point of the swinging, where the locational energy is 0, the total energy of the system is calculated as rotational inertia * rotational speed, and that is constant (without adding energy through applying forces). If the person moves body parts = mass further away from (or nearer to) the rotational center, the rotational inertia changes, and correspondigly, the rotational speed changes, and the product is  constant.

For a detailed explanation of rotational inertia (or moment of inertia), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia

Comment: You certainly *are* adding energy...