# Why does Parametric Resonance happen near twice the natural frequency

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators

I was working through Landau-Lifshitz Volume 1, and in section §27 he starts by expanding near $2\omega_0$, but he doesn't explain why.  I've tried expanding it using an unknown driving frequency, and putting $\omega_0+\epsilon$ in the ansatz where $\epsilon\ll1$.  I was planning on differentiating w.r.t. the frequency of the driving force and maximising the amplitude, but there isn't a nice way to apply the product-sum identities without losing either the $\omega_0+\epsilon$ (which is used to factorise everything into factors of $\cos(\omega_0+\epsilon)t$ and $\sin(\omega_0+\epsilon)t$.  I've also tried writing out the energy using the definition using the Lagrangian, but the result isn't super helpful and trying to maximise it didn't give anything helpful.  Why does Landau know to expand about $2\omega_0$?

Comment: are you talking about Landau-Lifshitz: Volume 1, §27, if not  please specify.

Comment: @hyportnex yes that's the section I'm talking about.  I'll add a line at the start to specify.

Comment: then remember that $2cos(2x+a)\cdot cos(x+b)=cos(x+a-b)-cos(3x+a+b)$ and $2cos(2x+a)\cdot sin(x+b)=sin(x+a-b)+sin(3x+a+b)$ , so that from $(2\omega_0 t)$ term multiplied by one having $(\omega_0 t)$ you get $(\omega_0 t)$ as in the equation in the paragraph below (27.9).